# How do I run OpenCV apps remotely (thru VNC/RDP)?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, xorg, vnc, opencv

What I want to accomplish: For my coursework I require to compile and execute OpenCV programs. It's all well, I installed the OpenCV library into the remote Debian server and compiled my first test application. Now here the problem starts: I cannot execute the compiled program without getting errors halting the execution. The error says

```
GLX not found. Aborting.
```

I tried fixing it by getting VirtualGL and running `/opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglrun <path to my app here>` but I get an error message saying `[VGL] ERROR: Could not open display :0.`. I am using TightVNC Server.

I'd rather not do X11 forwarding, only if it's the only option left, since I'm running a Windows host machine.